# Divide one column of dataset A with another columns of dataset B using R

Tags: r

I want to subtract all the content of a column of Dataset A with the content of a column of Dataset B and save the result.

Example:

```
datasetA  
datasetB
```

Columns, which I want to use:

```
datasetA$population   
datasetB$students
```

Now I want to create a new column, which includes all the population without students:

```
datasetA$new = datasetA$population - datasetB$students
```

Unfortunately this does not work.
Is tehre any generall resource how to deal with calculations using columns?

Comment: Presumably hose data set don't have the same number of rows?  You can look into `merge`.

Comment: Could you give us more informations? for instance the dimensions of the two datasets, structures, etc.. Also, what's the output of the command `datasetA$new = datasetA$population - datasetB$students`?

Comment: Right... they have not the same number of rows. Also the error states this problem.  I've used the suggested workaround with merge to copy the new columns to the datsets. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate and I did without errors:

```
> datasetA = data.frame(population=50:60)
> datasetB = data.frame(students=10:20)       
> datasetA$new = datasetA$population-datasetB$students
> datasetA
   population new
1          50  40
2          51  40
3          52  40
4          53  40
5          54  40
6          55  40
7          56  40
8          57  40
9          58  40
10         59  40
11         60  40
```

but there are some points you should consider:

```
> length(datasetA$population)==length(datasetB$students)
[1] TRUE
```

it means that the length of these two should be the same
also your data types should be numeric

```
> mode(datasetA$population)
[1] "numeric"
```